# Extract locators based on user actions

Tags: java, testing, automation, pageobjects

I want to create a program in Java to get the locators when you click on a button or when you write in a textfield. For example Login:

Username ----------------  (get the locator from textfield => id=username)
Buton Login  (get the locator from button =>  id=lgnBtn)
Finally I would like to create a program that extract all the locators based on user actions
Is it possible?